# Exception thrown after install xcode 3.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I found this problem after I install the latest SDK and Xcode version 3.2 Beta from Apple. Before install, my iPhone project compile correctly and has no any exception. But after I finished setup the latest SDK, I open my iPhone project to do some update. I compiled the project like I did before, no error report.

But after I run it in iPhone simulator, open the view that contains TableView, it throw an exception:

```
2010-02-01 14:07:03.924 SimpleApp[5458:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception

'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (UITableViewCellContentView)'
```

I am wondering something has change to my project's setting while XCode was updating. Could you help me by give me your idea or suggest some guideline to solve this? I'm ready to answer you more if you want more information about this bugs.

-EDIT-

I found that compile's log report the strange warning. I don't sure this is relate to the exception.

```
ld: warning: directory '/Volumes/Skiiing2/CD/ViewBased/Unknown Path/System/Library/Frameworks' following -F not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Click on your target, then click Info, then note your Configuration (you'll need to change it for all), then look under Search Paths->Framework Search Paths and delete the offending path.

Comment: Strangely, I also had this "Skiiing2" path mysteriously get added to my project somehow and I have no idea how as I don't have a drive named that.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was the same warning message that leads to Linker error. I found that Xcode 'escapes' ( prepend a '\' ) to my quote " in Library Search Paths. The directory was not found, causing the library not found and unable to link.